# Run through all possible values of character?

Tags: c, character

How can I write a program that runs through all possible values of a single character? For example, A, B, C, D, and so on, even going to ', :, /, etc.

Comment: That depends.  What encoding set are you talking about?  Unicode has a *lot* of characters, some of which won't even print out for your convenience.

Comment: What the heck's an *aesthetic character*? Unicode doesn't define that character class. You want *printable* characters?

Comment: Yup, that's what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "run through"?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted and closed?

Comment: @EvilTeach Poor judgment, abuse of power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to output all printable ASCII characters might be:

```
for (char c = ' '; c < 0x7f; c++) {
    putchar(c);
}
```

The set of printable Unicode characters is substantially larger.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* For ASCII */
for (int c = 0; c < 128; c++)
{
    if (isprint(c))
        putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char aestheticChars = "ABCD':/"; // add whatever characters you consider aesthetic

char c, char* p;
for (p = aestheticChars; (c = *p) != '\0'; p++)
{
  // do something with c
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving a correct solution without needing to know what "aesthetic" means :)

Answer (score -1):

For ASCII, have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/ for a table of what is considered whitespace, what's considered alphanumeric, printable, graphical, etc.  Then loop over the ranges that are of interest to you.

@GregHewgill's solution will give you all "printable" characters, but you might need to tweak it to get all "graphical" characters, or all "alphanumerc" characters.